# Creating new observations using information from a prior observation, and placing them into existing columns

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I apologize, as I was unsure how to phrase this in the title. I have no idea how to go about approaching this problem. I have a row of data, with an owner, percentage of credit to the owner, an employee, and a percentage of credit to the employee. I have provided an example row.

```
owner<- c("bob")
percentage_owner<- .75
employee<- c("sydney")
employee_percent<- .25
```

I am attempting to create a new row of data that places the owner's name into the employee column, and his percentage as the employees percentage, keeping all other columns the same in the new row, like so:

```
owner2<- c("bob", "bob")
percentage_owner2<- c(.75, .75)
employee2<- c("sydney", "bob")
employee_percent2<- c(.25,.75)
sample_data<-data.frame(owner, percentage_owner, employee, employee_percent)
goal_data<-data.frame(owner2, percentage_owner2, employee2,employee_percent2)
```

How would I go about doing this? I don't have much experience using R for this sort of data manipulation. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you have one row of data, and wants to add a second rows `data[2,] <- list("bob", .75, "bob", .75)`

Comment: I should have clarified, this would be one observation in a much larger dataset, in which I want to do this for each occurrence.

Comment: How are you getting the data?  If you get one observation, place those in a `list` for different columns and then rbind or update with row index (add one to the existing number of rows)

Answer (score 0):

We can either use `rbind` or update the already existing object with a `list` (why `list` is because vector (`c()`) cannot have mixed types

```
sample_data[nrow(sample_data) + 1,] <- list("bob", .75, "bob", .75)
sample_data
#  owner percentage_owner employee employee_percent
#1   bob             0.75   sydney             0.25
#2   bob             0.75      bob             0.75
```

---

if it is `rbind`, then `rbind` the `list` of values and update to same or different object

```
sample_data <- rbind(sample_data, list("bob", .75, "bob", .75))
sample_data
#  owner percentage_owner employee employee_percent
#1   bob             0.75   sydney             0.25
#2   bob             0.75      bob             0.75
#3   bob             0.75      bob             0.75
```